# Why is getchar() not working for me?

Tags: c, getchar

I've just started programming c and I'm working through The C Programming Language by Brian W.Kernighan and Dennis M.Richie.

One of the first examples is character counting and the following program is given, but when I enter a string no result it printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
   long nc;

   nc = 0;
   while (getchar() != EOF)
          ++nc; 
   printf("%ld\n",nc);
 }
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Please describe *exactly* what *"Isn't working"* means. Does your program compile?   When you run it, what input do you give it?  What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to finish the input. Your program will count characters until `EOF` is encountered. `EOF`, in the keyboard, can be sent by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> if you are in Windows, or <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> if you are in Linux/OS X.

Comment: Or try `./a.out <somefile`

Answer (score 3):

as an addition to the answers that were mentioned , here's how to make your program show results when pressing  `Enter`

```
 #include <stdio.h>

main()
{
   long nc;

   nc = 0;
   while (getchar() != '\n')
          ++nc; 
   printf("%ld\n",nc);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`getchar()` is buffered input. Since it is buffered, `The control will wait until you press` <kbd>Enter</kbd> key from the keyboard.
In your program, you are checking for `EOF` by doing

```
while (getchar() != EOF)
```

On windows, if you want EOF, you have to input a combination of 2 keys. i.e <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>.
If you are on LINUX, then EOF is combination of 2 keys <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>

As said earlier, control will wait at console until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so you have to press

- <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> - on windows.
- <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> - on LINUX.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send `EOF` to program by pressing <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> (for linux) or <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> (for Windows) to end the while loop.